# Facebook comments loading is increasing the register couting of the main page

Tags: facebook, comments, loading

I have an website where I show collection of pictures. Each collection has a lot of individual pictures on it.
I added the facebook comments plugin for each individual picture in order to allow the user comment and share in the facebook timeline. This is working properly.

I have an algorithm that count the number of access to the collection.

The problem is everytime that the each individual picture loads the plugin, as facebook is accessing the main collection page to get the info of the link, the collection counter is being increased. this happens in the first access.

I avoided it, removing this algorithm, but now when the user access the collection by the shared link, the counter will not be able to count this visit.

There is any way of track the origin of the facebook access to my page?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the official [FAQ](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) it will give you this hint:

> The fb:comments-count tag will emit the number of comments on your URL
>   in a  tag. You can then style this however appropriate to match
>   your site. Note this is currently not available in HTML5. For example,
>   to show the number of comments on example.com:.
>
> `<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments`